# Не импортируется Google Play Services

Tags: android-studio

В Android Studio выбираю File->New->Import Module указываю путь к папке C:\Users\Almaz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib. Студия пишет "Select modules to import". Пробовал выносить в другую папку, то же самое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `build.gradle` вашего модуля добавьте `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` в секцию `dependencies`. Так же для решения таких вопросов замечательно подходит [официальная документация](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)